# Lengths as equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, euclidean-geometry, math-history

From Wikipedia on [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition):

> The oldest definition of the **cardinality** of a set $X$ (implicit in
>   Cantor and explicit in Frege and Principia Mathematica) is as the
>   class $[X]$ of all sets that are equinumerous with $X$.

My question concerns Euclidean geometry, esp. Euclid's Elements in which there are no lengths (of line segments) that may be equal or not (as numbers) but *only* line segments themselves which may be equal (tacitly: with respect to length) or not.

> Who was the first to state explicitly that the **length** of a line
>   segment $l$ may be considered the class $[l]$ of all line
>   segments that are equal to $l$ (in the sense of Euclid)? And who can be assumed to have known or considered this implicitly? Euclid himself?

---

Probably not the first but a very important author did state it like this:

[image]

(Hartshorne, [Geometry: Euclid and beyond](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~wtaylor/agi.pdf) (1997), p. 3)

Comment: What equivalence class of line segments? What equals to what? Please elaborate.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this idea of treating abstractions as equivalence classes originated with Frege.